# access a local file when live on azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

My WCF service needs to access a local .cer file during runtime. In debug mode I'm able to access the file using this:

```
var testCertificate = new X509Certificate2(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/testCert.cer");
```

However, this does not work when my service is hosted on Azure. I am unsure as to why this might happen. Does the .cer file need a certain build mode, or be in a specific folder or something else? The file is deployed with the WCF service.

The exception message is:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Is this a file that is deployed with the Azure package?  Or is a temporary file generated by the Azure role?

Comment: A file deployed with the Azure package - as part of the WCF service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the .cer file's "Copy to Output Directory" property is set to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer". Otherwise it won't get packaged with your solution when you deploy to Azure.